# Gas estimation errored ...The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?

Tags: solidity, remix

So I am trying to implement a simple deposit contract deployed to the testnet of Binance smart chain. The code looks simple as following:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface IBEP20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
    function name() external view returns (string memory);
    function getOwner() external view returns (address);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool); // This is a function we gonna use
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool); // This is a function we gonna use
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract SimpleDeposit {
    function simpledeposit(address _tokenIn, uint256 _amountsIn) external {
        IBEP20(_tokenIn).approve(address(this), _amountsIn);
        IBEP20(_tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountsIn);
    }
}
```

I have some test BUSD in metamask wallet, so here `msg.sender` really means my wallet address. After deploying this contract, when I try to execute this function, the remix shows me the following errors:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": 3, "message": "execution reverted: BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance", "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002842455032303a207472616e7366657220616d6f756e74206578636565647320616c6c6f77616e6365000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" }
```

My question is how to properly fund a contract from my metamask wallet in this case? And also that the tranfer amount definitely not exceed the amounts of test BUSD in my test wallet.

Comment: approve does not work here,  because the caller of the approve function is the contract and not the msg.sender

Comment: Hello Majd, thx for your reply. Are you suggesting to change the arguments in approve() to msg.sender? I have tried this and not working.

Comment: No. You are calling „approve“ from inside the contract = the contract (not you) is trying to approve his token to itself(make no sense) and then the contract try to transfer token from you to itself , but it has no approvement from u to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the approve function directly from your wallet. You cant have your contract do that. So you'd need 2 transactions, one to the token contract that would be something like approve(yourContractAddress, amount) and one  to your `SimpleDeposit` contract calling the simpleDeposit function with the parameters you want. The way you tried to do it by coding it wont work because the ERC20/BEP20 standard `approve` function simply doesnt work that way

Comment: Hi @Foxxxey, thx for your answer! To be 100% clear, are you suggesting that I should add one more function to the contract playing the role of approve? Or you are suggesting something else off chain?

Comment: nop, sorry if i was unclear but you need to call the `approve` function of the token you want to deposit directly from your wallet (and not from your  contract, it wont work if you try to do that, since `approve` relies on `msg.sender`) before interacting with your contract.

Comment: notice how whenever you want to fund a contract (such as a pancakeswap pool for example) for the first time, you have to make 2 separate transactions, thats why (the 1st transaction is a call to the token contract, approving the contract you're trying to interact with to spend your tokens on your behalf, and the 2nd transaction is a call to the contract you want to interact with, actually funding the contract).

Comment: Ahhh, I see. So what I need to do is first delete the line about ```approve``` in my code. Then I need to send a transection from my wallet to the contract of whatever token I want to deposit. Just one more question, how exactly from my metamask wallet send an approval transection?

Comment: Thx, I figured out. You answer rocks!

Comment: Take care @CoolGas sending token to a contract may lock them their if the contract has no owner and method to transfer the token which it holds to others

Comment: @MajdTL i believe he's on testnet. But yeah that's true, as of right now there's no way for you to recover tokens sent to your contract.

Comment: Thx for you guys advice. Yes, I do realize that these tokens are now locked. Everything is just for test and chill.