# WBTC and Compound UDT approve does not work on rinkeby

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, rinkeby

[Here is WBTC code](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x577D296678535e4903D59A4C929B718e1D575e0A#code) and [here is Compound USDT code](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xd9ba894e0097f8cc2bbc9d24d308b98e36dc6d02#code) I am trying to interact with.

here is a brief of my code:

Imports:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
```

Interface:

```
interface RINKEBYTOKEN{
  function deposit() external payable;
  function transfer(address dst, uint wad) external returns (bool);
  function withdraw(uint wad) external;
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender)external view returns (uint256);
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external returns (bool);
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender,uint256 value);
}
```

Contract:

```
contract myToken is ERC20{
   bool stateOfApprove;

   RINKEBYTOKEN WBTC = RINKEBYTOKEN(0x577D296678535e4903D59A4C929B718e1D575e0A);
   RINKEBYTOKEN USDT = RINKEBYTOKEN(0xD9BA894E0097f8cC2BBc9D24D308b98e36dc6D02);

   function approveWBTC() public{
       stateOfApprove = WBTC.approve(address(this), uint256(2**25));
       emit Approval(msg.sender, address(this), uint256(2**25));
   }

   function showWBTCAllowance() public view  returns(uint256){
       return WBTC.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
   }

   function approveUSDT() public{
       stateOfApprove = USDT.approve(address(this), 2**25);
       emit Approval(msg.sender, address(this), 2**25);
   }

   function state() public view returns(bool){
       return stateOfApprove;
   }
}
```

I should note that I have tried changing interface name but doesn't work. Also when I replace `2**25` with `unit256(2**25)` doesn't work and vice versa. And one more thing is that Compound USDT seems not to have `allowance` function!

When I deploy contract, `stateOfApprove` is false and it is OK! But when I approve `stateOfApprove`becomes `true` but `showWBTCAllowance` returns `0`.

And when I want to transfer token I receive this error: `"message": "execution reverted: Insufficient allowance"`

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I cant really make sense of your code tbf. Also `WBTC.approve(address(this), uint256(2**25));` does not lets the contract spend `msg.sender` WBTC tokens (actually it just lets the contract spends its own tokens, which is useless) , that's simply not how ERC20 allowance works. You need to have your wallet address call `approve` on the WBTC contract directly

Comment: I'm actually working on a stable token which is backed by some tokens like BTC (in ethereum network and polygon is WBTC) and ETH and USDT and some more. This is the begin of contract. when contract receives some token, gets price of the token from chainlink oracle and mints some stable token to the caller. Now I am trying to receive token from a person. Took the example of how to receive token from a person from https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/transfers-and-approval-of-erc-20-tokens-from-a-solidity-smart-contract/

Comment: So how should I code the function of it?! And also how does it work?!

Comment: To take ERC20 tokens from the user just use `token.transferFrom`, but there is no way for you to approve the token trough your contract, you have to approve it directly from the token contract (by calling`approve` on it. Maybe read this? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/106390/gas-estimation-errored-the-transaction-execution-will-likely-fail-do-you-wan/106400#106400 it describes more or less the same problem as yours